# Passing variable between servers php

Tags: php, variables, file-get-contents

I'm trying to obtain variable from one script and get it in other script located on another server.
script1.php

```
$variable1 = "hello";
```

On other server I have script2.php:

```
$file = file_get_contents ('http://example.com/script1.php');
echo $file;
```

Comment: Instead of stating that it doesn't, can you explain why you thought it would work? Any specific server precautions so script1 isn't just run on server1? Why the `$variable1` as `$context` parameter for [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) in `script2`? Did you search and look at any other questions before this?

Comment: `file_get_contents` loads the rendered code. If it was able to pull the source code of any server think of how insecure every website would be

Comment: Agree with @user3783243, however you can echo $variable1 in your script1.php and use curl inside script2.php to get the returned data or you can use Ajax.